# Jenkins + populate changes from last build

Tags: git, svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson

I am using svn and git as my source code repository and Jenkins for build. In a single job I need to checkout sources from different repositories (svn & git) and from different paths. Hence I use a customized script for checking out the code from svn and git. Since I doesn't use the feature of Jenkins to checkout, I am not able to generate the changes from last build. Is there any way I can achieve this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the steps you followed in the script? How did you pass the credentials in script?

Comment: Credentials are not passed to the script as I have already configured the access with svn+ssh. The repositories are very huge and hence cheking out an entire branch will take a lot of time. To avoid this, in the script its mentioned to checkout from different required parts of the branch and some part of the code is in svn and some in git. :(